# Como puedo distribuir los elementos de un arreglo principal a otros 2 arreglos lo mas balanceada posible

Tags: java

Tengo un conjunto de 2N jugadores cada uno de los cuales tiene asociados un indicador numérico mayor que cero que define la calidad como jugador. A partir de este conjunto de jugadores, debo crear dos equipos de N jugadores, A y B, tales que la suma de los indicadores de calidad de sus componentes sea lo más similar posible.

Tengo esto preparado

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Arreglo de jugadores
        int[] equipoDeJuego = {8,8,9,6,1,7,1,3,7,5}; 
        int fuerzaA=0;
        int fuerzaB=0;

        //Equipo A
        int[] A=new int[10];

        //Equipo A
        int[] B= new int[10];

        //Se imprime la cantidad de los jugadores
        //System.out.println("Cantidad de jugadores: "+equipoDeJuego.length);

        //Ordenamos el arreglo de manera creciente
        Arrays.sort(equipoDeJuego);



        for(int i=0; i<(equipoDeJuego.length)/2; i++) {

            //Integrantes del primer arreglo
            A[i]=equipoDeJuego[i];
            System.out.print("Equipo A:"+A[i]+" ");

            fuerzaA+=A[i];
        }
        System.out.println("Fuerza equipo A: "+fuerzaA);
        System.out.println();


      for(int i=5; i<10; i++) {

            //Integrantes del segundo arreglo
            B[i]=equipoDeJuego[i];
            System.out.print("Equipo B:"+B[i]+" ");
            fuerzaB+=B[i];

        }
        System.out.println("Fuerza equipo B: "+fuerzaB);



        int dF= fuerzaB-fuerzaA;
        System.out.println("La diferencia es: "+dF);


  }
}
```

Este código que hice me di cuenta que no resuelve el problema eficientemente, porque abra un equipo que tendrá A=(1,1,1,1,1,1) y el equipo B=(6), se balancea pero se que no es la mejor practica.

Como puedo crear un código que pueda distribuir la fuerza entre los equipos, es decir, ir lanzado a los mejores en ambos equipos basado en su diferencia hasta que ese equipo sea mejor que el otro.

Ejemplo:

```
int[] equipoDeJuego = {8,8,9,6}; 
Equipo A={8,9}; 
Equipo B={8,6};
```

Comment: A mi lo más equitativo me parece que ordenes la lista de jugadores por el ranking y luego los jugadores pares en un equipo y los impares en otro. Debe ser una distribución bastante justa. Entiendo que sabes como implementarlo pero si necesitas ayuda... aquí estoy.

Comment: Si lo que quieres es que quede lo más balanceado posible en base a la calidad de los jugadores, creo que tu ejemplo de 6 contra 1 está bien. Otra cosa será si para ti prima que tengas el mismo número de jugadores sobre que los equipos estén balanceados. Personalmente me parece que poner a 6 niños a jugar contra un adulto entrenado es la mejor solución al caso propuesto.

Comment: Optaría por que la primera iteración se vayan metiendo los jugadores en el equipo con menor puntuación. Luego sacaría la diferencia de calidad entre equipos y luego desplazaría del equipo mas fuerte, los jugadores que sumados sus calidades sean la mitad de la diferencia entre equipos. Si primas el equilibrio de calidad, esta solución te vale. Si quieres equipos equilibrados con calidades similares, habria que darle otra vuelta de tuerca y hacer un [algoritmo de mochila multiple](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_de_la_mochila)

Comment: *Este código que hice me di cuenta que no resuelve el problema eficientemente, porque abra un equipo que tendrá A=(1,1,1,1,1,1) y el equipo B=(6), se balancea pero se que no es la mejor practica.* Bien, eso es algo que preguntar al profesor/cliente: ¿tiene alguna influencia el número de jugadores? Igual da por supuesto que entiendes que los equipos tienen el mismo número de jugadores, igual le da lo mismo... Son dos problemas distintos con soluciones distintas, así que deberías saber cuál de ellos tienes que resolver.

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev necesito tu ayuda

Comment: @SJuan76 Tienes razon

Answer (score 0):

Esto es problema de partición. Tiene varias soluciones, unas mejores otras no tanto. Mi propuesta es bastante mala. Te pongo aquí un poco de código donde **a1** es la propuesta mía de arriba y **a2** es un método algo mejor pero aun así no da demasiado buenos resultados.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Team {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // jugadores
        Integer[] equipoDeJuego = { 8, 8, 9, 6, 1, 7, 1, 3, 7, 5 };

        int f = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < equipoDeJuego.length; i++) {
            f += equipoDeJuego[i];
        }
        System.out.println("Fuerza total: " + f + ", fuerza media: " + ((float) f / 2));

        a1(equipoDeJuego);

        a2(equipoDeJuego);

    }

    static void a1(Integer[] equipo) {
        System.out.println("Intento 1");

        // el tamaño del equipo resultante sería la mitad del número de jugadores
        int size = equipo.length / 2;

        // Equipo A (el nombre en minúsculas que es más javero)
        int[] a = new int[size];

        // Equipo B (idem)
        int[] b = new int[size];

        int fuerzaA = 0;
        int fuerzaB = 0;

        // ordenar
        Arrays.sort(equipo);

        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < equipo.length; i += 2) {
            a[counter] = equipo[i];
            b[counter] = equipo[i + 1];
            counter++;
        }

        System.out.print("Equipo A: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(a[i] + ",");
            fuerzaA += a[i];
        }
        System.out.println("\tFuerza equipo A: " + fuerzaA);

        System.out.print("Equipo B: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(b[i] + ",");
            fuerzaB += b[i];
        }
        System.out.println("\tFuerza equipo B: " + fuerzaB);

        // hay un reparto más justo:
        // 1 3 6 8 9 -> 27
        // 1 5 7 7 8 -> 28
    }

    static void a2(Integer[] equipo) {
        System.out.println("Intento 2");

        int size = equipo.length / 2;

        List<Integer> equipoA = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> equipoB = new ArrayList<>();

        int fuerzaA = 0;
        int fuerzaB = 0;

        // ordenar
        Arrays.sort(equipo);

        // hay que iterar en orden inverso
        for (int i = equipo.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (sum(equipoA) < sum(equipoB)) {
                equipoA.add(equipo[i]);
            } else {
                equipoB.add(equipo[i]);
            }
        }

        // esto es un ajuste por si las dos listas no terminan con el mismo tamaño movemos el último elemento
        // pero si las dos listas son muy desiguales esto no funciona
        if (equipoA.size() > equipoB.size()) {
            Integer temp = equipoA.remove(equipoA.size() - 1);
            equipoB.add(temp);
        }
        if (equipoB.size() > equipoA.size()) {
            Integer temp = equipoB.remove(equipoB.size() - 1);
            equipoA.add(temp);
        }

        Integer[] a = new Integer[size];
        Integer[] b = new Integer[size];

        // las listas a arrays
        equipoA.toArray(a);
        equipoB.toArray(b);

        System.out.print("Equipo A: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i] == null) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.print(a[i] + ",");
            try {
                fuerzaA += a[i];
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // por si queda algún null
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\tFuerza equipo A: " + fuerzaA);

        System.out.print("Equipo B: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            if (b[i] == null) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.print(b[i] + ",");
            try {
                fuerzaB += b[i];
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\tFuerza equipo B: " + fuerzaB);

    }

    // suma de los elementos de una lista de enteros
    private static int sum(List<Integer> a) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (Integer i : a) {
            sum += i;
        }
        return sum;
    }

}
```

Si quieres seguir investigando - [aquí](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1265125/Fast-and-Practically-perfect-Partition-Problem-Sol) tienes un ejemplo algo complejo pero tiene buena pinta e implementa unos cuantos algoritmos. Y para no hacer de menos la [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem), un poco de teoría.